# prog to read students particulars such as roll etc from key board using array?

Tags: java

```
import java. util.*; 
class student
{
    private int rollno;
    private int age;
    private String sex;
    private float height;
    private float weight;

    void getinfo()
    {
        System.out.println("enter the roll no of the student");
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        rollno=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the age of student");
        Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
        age=obj1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the sex of the student");
        Scanner obj3=new Scanner(System.in);
        sex=obj3.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter the heighrt of student ");
        Scanner obj4=new Scanner(System.in);
        height=obj4.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("enter the weight of the student");
        Scanner obj5=new Scanner(System.in);
        weight=obj5.nextFloat();

    }

    void disinfo()
    {
        System.out.println(rollno);
        System.out.println(age); 
        System.out.println(sex);
        System.out.println(height);
        System.out.println(weight);
    }
}


public class str
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        student object[]=new student[5];
        System.out.println("enter the number of student");
        int i;
        int n;
        Scanner obj6=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=obj6.nextInt();

        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            object[i].getinfo();
        }

        System.out.println("diplaying the result");

        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            object[i].disinfo();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: if I had the power to edit, I would. this is very hard to read and your question isn't very specific. :(

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add setters and getters to the class `student`. In Java, class names have the first letter in upper case. `object` is a keyword, so you cannot name any variables like so. In Java, arrays are zero based, so starting a loop from 1 will skip the first array location. In this part of your code:

```
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            object[i].disinfo();
        }
```

You are most likely to get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` since you are creating an array of 5 locations and then, try to access a number of locations that is given by the user, and you do not make any checks either.

So basically... create setters and getters for your fields in the class named `Student`. In the main class, create an array of students. Create a loop, and within the loop, ask the user to provide the information, such as age, sex, etc.

I strongly suggest you take a look at some beginner tutorials or books.